# Angular 8 app deployed on nginx in docker - GET, PUT, POST, PATCH not working

Tags: angular, docker, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Angular app deployed in nginx on docker does not connects with java backend api. GET method returns html instead of object, POST, PUT, PATCH has 405 Not Allowed

I've got working angular * app with backend api (java spring boot). Angular app running in IDE has already cofigured proxy.conf.json and works with chrome cors passing any request to backend. Problem started when I've deployed angular app on nginx (tried 1.15.0, 1.16.0, 1.17.0) in docker. None of http.client operations does not want to work. GET returns http code instead of json/javascript-object. POST, PATCH, PUT returns 405 Not allowed.

It looks like for me that problem is with inappropriate nginx configuration but in the other hand I've tested a lot of reverse-proxy and cors configurations with the same result...

Angular app: http://localhost:8100 (running from docker)
Spring boot api: http://localhost:8081 (running from IDE)

angular build with command:

```
ng build --prod
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.17.0

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY prm-web-app/ usr/share/nginx/html/

EXPOSE 8100
```

nginx.conf:

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/json;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    upstream api_server {
        server localhost:8081;
    }

    server {
        listen       8100;
        server_name example;
        index index.html index.htm;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location / {
          add_header Allow 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE' always;
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
          add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;

          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /api {
            add_header Allow 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE' always;
            proxy_pass http://api_server;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }        
    }
}
```

angular extras for examples:

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
    const body = res;
    return body || { };
  }
private httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Request-With, Content-type, Accept, X-Access-Token',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS'
  });
```

angular example GET operation:

```
getAppointment(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(apiEndpoint + '/' + id).pipe(
      map(this.extractData),
      catchError( err => {
        this.logger.logError(ErrorLevel.ERROR, JSON.stringify(err));
        err = this.handleError(err);
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
```

angular example POST operation:

```
postSearchTimeSlot(searchTimeSlotPostRequest: SearchTimeSlotPostRequest): Observable<any> {
    const options = {headers: this.httpHeaders};
    return this.http.post(searchTimeSlotEndpoint + '/', searchTimeSlotPostRequest, options).pipe(
      map(this.extractData),
      catchError(err => {
        this.logger.logError(ErrorLevel.ERROR, JSON.stringify(err));
        err = this.handleError(err);
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
  }
```

I've tried solutions like:

```
error_page 405 =200 $uri;
```

and:

```
error_page 405 = @app;

location @app {
proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/api;
}
```

and: 
added application/json to mime.types
and:

```
const options = {headers: this.httpHeaders, responseType: 'json' as 'json'};
const options = {headers: this.httpHeaders, responseType: 'text' as 'json'};
```

and:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer(){
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("PUT", "POST", "PATCH", "GET")
                        .allowCredentials(true).maxAge(3600);
            }
        };
    }


    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

and few other with proxy_pass and add_header for nginx.
Now I'm already lack of ideas...

Every time there are the same issues (tested on latest chrome and mozilla firefox):
for GET request:

```
{
"headers": {
"normalizedNames": {},
"lazyUpdate": null
},
"status": 200,
"statusText": "OK",
"url": "http://localhost:8100/appointment_api/api/v1/appointment/123412341234",
"ok": false,
"name": "HttpErrorResponse",
"message": "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8100/appointment_api/api/v1/appointment/123412341234",
"error": {
"error": {},
"text": "<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.ab8e79b2d91e978b1e50.css"></head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.b8312458afdf3a7f4969.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.741402d1d47331ce975c.js" nomodule></script><script src="polyfills-es5.8de8aa8baf008bce96d4.js" nomodule></script><script src="scripts.99edbfa41b8b40270fe5.js"></script><script src="main-es2015.49e5dbe84808fb269a5d.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.628bd9db49e6b16c7a86.js" nomodule></script></body>
</html>
"
}
}
```

above error code in browser is because angular expects json by default but nginx returns html instad of json.

for PUT,POST, PATCH request:

```
"status": 405,
"statusText": "Not Allowed",
"url": "http://localhost:8100/appointment_api/api/v1/searchTimeSlot/",
"ok": false,
"name": "HttpErrorResponse",
"message": "Http failure response for http://localhost:8100/appointment_api/api/v1/searchTimeSlot/: 405 Not Allowed",
"error": "<html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.17.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

For both issues no clue what to blame and how to fix this

Comment: What is localhost 8081 going to be *inside the container*?

Comment: No, java api under localhost:8081 is running directly from intellij Idea. Later I want to dockerize all api's but of trying small steps for now

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

It was docker which was blocking traffic from nginx to API - (I was testing dockerized angular on nginx, but api were  running directly from IDE.

Solution was to create docker compose which will combine all necessary modules (api and front-end) in one docker network, or (as I did) deploy directly on kubernetes and configure services.